# Dynamically add data to a js object

Tags: javascript, oop

I am trying to use a for loop to add content into an object.

For Example:

`var p = { "1": "value", "2": "value", "3": "value" };`

Is there a way to use a for loop to add `"1", "2", "3"` and their property(if the property is the same) into var p?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to add new properties to an object:

```
var obj = {

};

for (var i = 1; i < 3; i++ ) {
// using dot notation
// obj.i = "value"; 

// using square bracket notation
obj[i] = value3; // use this in your case

}
```

The dot notation is used when you know the key name and second form is used when key is pro grammatically generated so in your case the square notation will be used

Comment: Note that the first form will add a attribute `i` to the object, like so: `obj = {"i": "value"}`. In this case, bracket notation should be used, so you can insert a expression inside the bracket (in this case, the variable `i`), resulting in the following object: `obj {"1":"value", "2":"value", "3":"value"}`.

Comment: Corrected and cleared the confusion, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Thanks a lot for that just one more question how would the for loop change if I wanted my object to be as such                           var data = { '1.jpg': { caption: '' }, '2.jpg': { caption: '' }, '3.jpg': { caption: '' }, '4.jpg': { caption: '' }}; If the 1.jpg and 2.jpg and their captions were added dynamically using the for loop

Comment: If i have understood it correctly then you can do obj[i + '.jpg'] = { 'caption' : 'This is your caption ' + i }; if your caption also needs to be incremented but the caption will also be object that you can access like this obj['1.jpg'].caption